# Stop slots from being executed

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In Qt, I can `emit` a signal, to which I have multiple slots connected, where in the case of direct connections, the connected slots are called on after another.

Let `void mySignal(int x)` be the signal of the class `MyClass`.

Depending on the value of `x` I want to perform a different action, and under the assumption, I want to do exactly one action, I can connect a slot, with a `switch-case` construct to execute the relevant action.

This implies that I need to know beforehand what kind of values I can get, and what the actions are.

I can also connect a slot for each of my actions, and guard the execution by a `if` clause. Now I can just connect whatever I want, whenever I want it. But under the assumption that I want to do exactly one action, it would be performance-wise beneficial if I could stop further execution of the slots, when I found the 'match'.

```
[...]
QObject::connect(this, &MyClass::mySignal, this, [this](int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        qDebug() << x; // Stop it now!;
    }
});
QObject::connect(this, &MyClass::mySignal, this, [this](int x) {
    if (x == 4) {
        qDebug() << x; // Stop it now!;
    }
});
QObject::connect(this, &MyClass::mySignal, this, [this](int x) {
    if (x == 109) {
        qDebug() << x; // Stop it now!; 
    }
});
```

> Is there a way, to tell the signal, to not execute anymore slots, **until the signal is emitted again**?

Comment: I see it complicated since the calls to the slots are not sequential so maybe you could call the other slots, but those that are already running I think stopping them would be impossible. I think you are doing a problem unnecessarily because as a switch or a small logic you can do it

Comment: @eyllanesc: It would be no problem if there are already some running, when they are not a `direct connection` because that can be easily handle by the `if`-clause. The `switch` has the downside, that I can't plug in and plug out as I seem fit, on run-time. The only way I can see would be using a map between the key and a functor (python-style). But as I am in the Qt framework, it would be *awsome* if there would be something already available.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to drop the signal slot idea and use something else e.g. `std::map<int, void (*)()>` instead? This would call exactly one function. You could/should even check whether the key is already in map before you do the call. (Of course, this might be extended to object/method pairs as well or even `std::function`.)

Comment: @Scheff: That was an idea I also propsed 20 mins ago, and that I am investigating right now. I still think it would be awsome, if I could use something from the framework, instead of creating my own way. There might be some possibility with events maybe.

Comment: "I could use something from the framework." Yeah, but it smells somehow like _abuse_ considering all the function calls and if-s to provide something like an "extendable switch"...

Comment: I would consider `std::map<>` and `std::function<>` the better "framework" for what you intend to do.

Comment: @derM please elaborate after which condition do you need the slots to be executed again?

Comment: @vahancho: Unconditionally when the signal is emitted the next time.

Comment: So, I have tried and implemented a quick and dirty proof of concept to *ab* use the QEvent-System. I will now try the `std::map<>` and `std::function<>` solution, that seems to be favored.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something like this, *(ab)* using the Qt framework would use the `QEvent`-system.

The signal handler won't do more, than translating the signal in an `QEvent`.  Instead of all the separate slots, install `eventFilter`. If the `eventFilter` accepts the event, return `true` to stop the propagation to other (filter)objects.

> The code is just a quick and dirty test and has no security precautions. It might easily crash hard.

*// testevent.h*

```
#ifndef TESTEVENT_H
#define TESTEVENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QEvent>

class TestEvent: public QEvent
{
    int m_x;
public:
    TestEvent(int x = 0);
    int x() { return m_x; }

};

class TestEventFilter: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_fx;
public:
    TestEventFilter(int fx, QObject* parent = nullptr);
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
}; 
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TestEvent)

#endif // TESTEVENT_H
```

// testevent.cpp

```
#include "testevent.h"
#include <QDebug>

TestEvent::TestEvent(int x)
    : QEvent(QEvent::User)
    , m_x(x)
{
}

TestEventFilter::TestEventFilter(int fx, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_fx(fx)
{
}

bool TestEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(obj);
    TestEvent* e = static_cast<TestEvent*>(event);
    qDebug() << "EventFilter for" << m_fx << "got" << e;
    if (e->x() == m_fx) {
        qDebug() << "accept that event!";
        event->accept();
        return true;
    }
    event->ignore();
    return false;
}
```

*// run*

```
QObject o;

TestEventFilter* f1 = new TestEventFilter(10);
TestEventFilter* f2 = new TestEventFilter(5);
TestEventFilter* f3 = new TestEventFilter(3);
TestEventFilter* f4 = new TestEventFilter(7);

o.installEventFilter(f1);
o.installEventFilter(f2);
o.installEventFilter(f3);
o.installEventFilter(f4);

qApp->sendEvent(&o, new TestEvent(5));
qApp->sendEvent(&o, new TestEvent(3));
```

Output:

> EventFilter for 7 got 0x369f2fe0
>   EventFilter for 3 got 0x369f2fe0
>   EventFilter for 5 got 0x369f2fe0
>   accept that event!
>   EventFilter for 7 got 0x369f3250
>   EventFilter for 3 got 0x369f3250
>   accept that event!